# Add subview to arbitary activity android

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

I'm going to show notification in any view in my Android application, but I didn't find any way how to do it without getting current activity.

On iOS we can just do

```
Window.AddSubview(customNotification);
```

But is there any way to do it in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you refer to notifications in Android, it means the notifications you can see out side the app (see [notifications documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) for an explanation). I assume this is not what you are referring to because you are referring to the iOS `Window`.

Android also has a `Window` class. However, an `Activity` is usually the right UI component you should be looking at when adding a custom `View`. As opposed to iOS, an Android app almost always needs to work in a certain `Context` to add UI components and you can't just add one to a static Window.

My suggestion is then to change the logic a bit. I assume you have a running Activity at any point (if otherwise and you are running from a `Service`, perhaps notifications are the right solution after all). So what you can do is to broadcast your request to show certain data and the active Activity will pick it up and add your custom view to itself in the right spot.

Another option is to start a new dialog Activity using the application context.

Comment: Dialog Activity, that's what I was looking for